# Difficulty comparing values with keyup and change on html textboxes

Tags: jquery, html

I have two textboxes that will be used to search for the amount of Weapon, therefore Weapon Range Amount.

Either of the two is blank is ok, but the 2nd textbox shouldnt be greater than the value of the 1st textbox.

I'm torn between the tests made by keyup and change

the code's behavior is

1)Input 11(higher number) on 1st textbox
2)hit Tab
3)Input 2(lower number) on the 2nd
4)alert fires up

11>2 right? but the it still got inside the

```
if (weaponLess < weaponMore)
```

fyi

```
var weaponLess=$("#weaponAmtSuuji1").val();
var weaponMore=$("#weaponAmtSuuji2").val();
```

seems it compared the value of the 2nd textbox before it got an input

I have a hidden textbox which I showed on the code, and it should capture both of the input and should check if each of the two has an input or none

then join the inputs in a pattern like "`WeaponAmount` < "+txtBox1+" AND `WeaponAmount` > "+txtBox2"

html

```
Search Weapon Amount Range
<br>
<label>Weapon Amount Less</label>&nbsp
<input type="text" id="weaponAmtSuuji1"/>&nbsp<span id="weaponAmtErrmsg1"></span>&nbsp
<br>
<label>Weapon Amount More</label>&nbsp
<input type="text" id="weaponAmtSuuji2"/>&nbsp<span id="weaponAmtErrmsg2"></span>
<br>
<input type="text" name="WeaponAmount" id="weaponAmtFld">
```

jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/yuuto/75V8S/

you may noticed I put

```
/*$('#weaponAmtFld').val(function(index, val) {
 if (val.indexOf("AND")>0)...
```

on comment, if removed it, the script doesnt seem to perform even the

```
if (weaponLess < weaponMore) {
```

parts

really need help

Comment: 11>2 right? -> not necessarily (on a string compare, 11 is lower than 2 because of the alphanumeric order)

Comment: before I forget, I restricted the textboxes to accept only numbers

Comment: event if they accept numbers, the type must be number (try typeof on your variables)

Answer (score 1):

String compare rules :) (see my comment)

http://jsfiddle.net/75V8S/2/

```
if (parseInt(weaponLess) < parseInt(weaponMore)) {
```

Comment: have you tried inputting say 11 for 1st field and 2 for the 2nd? the script fires the alert even if the inputs are valid

Comment: Hell yeah, there is another bug here :/

Comment: my next guess is that you use the same variable for all your events, I try to fix that...

Comment: here we are: http://jsfiddle.net/75V8S/3/ in fact you had another string comparison :p
This may be nicely factorised, you know?

Comment: Thanks for fixing, now before copying values to weaponAmtFld, I would like to make my code $('#weaponAmtFld').val(function(index, val) {
     if (val.indexOf("AND")>0)
        {
          val=val.replace(/.+?AND/,"`BetAmount` < "+event.target.value+ " AND");
          return val;
        }
        else
          return "`BetAmount` < "+event.target.value+" AND";
        } to work, coz it doesnt work inside the else branch

Comment: this is relatively silly, what do you expect to achieve by declaring a function there?

Comment: I debugged many errors from that commented part but I do not understand what you expect to achieve from that http://jsfiddle.net/75V8S/5/

Comment: yeah it looks silly, anyway I found it on net but it works btw I appreciate your help Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome. What do you want this code to do? (and do not forget to validate the answer)